# Linear algebra question - an example

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading linear representations of finite groups by Serre and I want to understand what is meant by the following via an example:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{C}$ (unless stated otherwise) of complex numbers and let $GL(V)$ be the group of all *automorphisms* of $V$. An element $\alpha$ of $GL(V)$ is, by definition, a linear mapping of $V$ into $V$. When $V$ has finite dimension, say $n$, this implies we have a finite basis $\lbrace e_{i} \rbrace$ of $n$ elements with linear map
>   $\alpha\colon V \rightarrow V$ defined by a square matrix
>   $(\alpha_{ij})$ of order $n$, where the coefficients $\alpha_{ij}$ are
>   complex numbers. Given a basis $\lbrace e_{i} \rbrace$ of $V$ and an automorphism $\alpha$ in $GL(V)$, then for every basis vector $\lbrace e_{i} \rbrace$ we have:
>
> $$
> \alpha(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij}e_j
> $$
>
> An alternative definition to saying that $\alpha$ is an automorphism is to say that the determinant $\det(\alpha_{ij})$ is non zero. Therefore, the group $GL(V)$-- 
>   the general linear group on $V$ is thus isomorphic to *the group of invertible (or non-singular) square matrices of order $n$*.

I would appreciate if anyone can help.

***EDIT***: for example let $V=\mathbb{C}^3$ but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: I want an example so I can see what's going on. so for example if $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ then we have $\lbrace e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3} \rbrace$. now what is $\alpha$ in this example?and how what is the matrix of $\alpha_{ij}$

Comment: Serre is talking about vector spaces over $\Bbb{C}$, how is $\Bbb{R}^3$ a $\Bbb{C}$-vector space? Do you mean $V=\Bbb{C}^3$?

Comment: @Javi that's what I meant yes

Comment: This is the standard way of turning a linear operator into a matrix, given a basis for the space, i.e. transform each basis vector and put the coordinates of these transformed vectors into columns of a matrix. This is part of any linear algebra course. Have you never encountered this?

Comment: @Javi Well, the field being $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ really does not matter here anyway.

Comment: @TheoBendit No because I am self teaching

Comment: @BillO'Haran Agree, but the OP might be confusing basic notions, so I just wanted to make sure the problem was not related to the base field.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of bases and coordinate vectors with respect to a given a basis?

Comment: I'd appreciate if I can get a worked example as this is how I learn most efficiently as I can see what's going on

Comment: @TheoBendit I believe so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this is finding the matrix for a transformation given a basis, and is a standard thing in finite-dimensional linear algebra. I went hunting for some nice account for how to do this, but they all seemed to make what I see as a pedagogical error: they start the explanation in $\Bbb{R}^n$, which I think confuses the matter. Let's take a classic but different example.

Consider the vector space $V = P_2(\Bbb{C})$, the space of complex polynomials of degree $2$ or less. An arbitrary element of $V$ is a function $x \mapsto ax^2 + bx + c$, where $x$ is a complex variable. Addition and scalar multiplication are defined pointwise, and are exactly what one would expect.

One basis for this space is $(1, x, x^2)$; the constant function $1$, the identity function, and the squaring function. The map above can be written as a unique linear combination of these three functions:
$$ax^2 + bx + c = a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot x + c \cdot 1.$$
As such, we can form the corresponding coordinate column vector in $\Bbb{C}^3$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} c \\ b \\ a \end{bmatrix}.$$
This coordinate column vector is dependent on the particular basis. We could take a different basis $(x^2, x - 1, (x + 1)^2)$, and get a totally different coordinate vector for the same polynomial.

In this way, each basis represents a way to express the polynomials in $V$ as ordered triples of complex numbers in $\Bbb{C}^3$ (I'm trying to avoid using the word "vector" here). Indeed, any basis of any finite-dimensional vector space gives us a correspondence between the space and $n$-tuples of scalars. Different bases will produce different correspondences, but it shows that the spaces are structurally identical to powers of the scalar field.

Now, given a fixed basis for $V$, linear operators on $V$ can be seen to be linear operators on $\Bbb{C}^3$, mapping not the polynomials in $V$, but their coordinate vectors with respect to a given basis. As it turns out, such linear operators on $\Bbb{C}^3$ can always be uniquely envisioned as multiplication by a $3 \times 3$ complex matrix. This matrix is the matrix $(\alpha_{ij})$ referred to in the book.

To form this matrix, you compute the transformation on each basis vector individually, then writing the results as coordinate column vectors, with respect to the basis. The matrix whose columns are these coordinate vectors is the matrix in question. If $T$ is the operator, then it is the unique matrix $A$ that has the property that
$$A[v]_B = [Tv]_B$$
where $[v]_B$ is the coordinate column vector of $v$ with respect to $B$.

---

Time for a concrete example. Consider the linear operator $D$, the differentiation map. It maps from $V$ to $V$. Fix the usual basis for $V$: $B = (1, x, x^2)$. We compute
$$D(1) = 0 = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \implies [D(1)]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
This is the first column of the matrix. Then,
$$D(x) = 1 = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \implies [D(x)]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
This is the second column. Finally the third column:
$$D(x^2) = 2x = 0 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \implies [D(x^2)]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
In total, the matrix for $D$ under $B$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

In order to use it, consider differentiating a polynomial $(x + 1)^2$. First, we write it as a coordinate column vector:
$$[(x + 1)^2]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, we multiply it to the above matrix:
$$[D(x + 1)^2]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
To confirm, we have that $D(x + 1)^2 = D(x^2 + 2x + 1) = 2x + 2$, which corresponds to the above calculation. In this way, we understand differentiation on $V$ as a simple matrix multiplication.

Note also that this matrix is not invertible, as there is no inverse to differentiation (indefinite integration doesn't count, due to the constant of integration)!

Comment: One quick question, where you assign the column vectors $[D(1)]_B$, shouldn't the second and third vectors be $[D(x)]_B$ and $[D(x^2)]_B$ where you've written the implies sign? probably a small typo when copying and pasting aha but I wouldn't want to confuse future readers!

Comment: @john Ah yes, whoops!

Comment: having reread it, shouldn't it be $$\begin{bmatrix} c \\ b \\ a \end{bmatrix}.$$ ??

Comment: Yes @john, you're absolutely right.