# Find the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $L: P_1 \rightarrow P_3$ be the linear transformation defined by
>   $L(p(t)) = t^2 p(t)$.
>
> Let $S = \{t, t+1\}$ be a basis for $P_1$ and $T = \{t^3, t^2-1, t,
>  t+1\}$ be a basis for $P_3$.
>
> Find the matrix of $L$ with respect to $S$ and $T$. Find $L(2t-3)$
>   using the definition of $L$.

What I've tried so far and I do not know what to do next

$a_1 = t$

$L(a_1) = L(t) = t^2(t) = t^3$

$a_2 = t+1$

$L(a_2) = L(t+1) = (t+1)^2(t+1) = t^3+3t^2+3t+1$

Comment: Next step is to write $L(a_1)$ and $L(a_2)$ as linear combinations of the elements of $T$. The vectors of coefficients form the columns of the matrix.

Comment: Here's an example I posted a year ago, under a different account: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188704/linear-algebra-question-an-example/3188762#3188762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to represent the images of the elements of $S$ in the basis vectors of $T$. We have

$$L(t) = t^3 = 1t^3 + 0(t^2 - 1)+ 0t + 0 (t + 1),$$

hence $(1, 0, 0, 0)$ is the first column vector of the matrix of $L$, say $A$. Now note that $L(t + 1) = t^2 (t + 1) = t^3 + t^2$ and therefore

$$L(t + 1) = t^3 + t^2 = 1t^3 + 1(t^2 - 1) - 1t + 1(t + 1).$$

It follows that

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I leave it to you to calculate $L(2t - 3)$.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1
 & 1 \\ 
 0&1 \\
 0& -1\\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}2
\\ 
-3
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-1
\\ -3
\\ 3
\\ -3

\end{bmatrix}$
is this correct calculating $L(2t-3)$

Comment: No, you first have to expand $2t - 3$ in the basis $S$. This is, find $a$ and $b$ such that $2t - 3 = at + b(t + 1)$.

Comment: btw, how did it become (1, 1, -1, 1) and not (1, 1, 0, 0) since $t^3 + t^2$ exist only

Comment: You have to express $t^3 + t^2$ in the basis $T$. What you always want to do is to use the standard basis $\{1, t, t^2, t^3 \}$ which you don't have here. In the basis $T$, the vector $(1, 1, 0, 0)$ would correspond to $1t^3 + 1(t^2 - 1) = t^3 + t^2 - 1 \neq t^3 + t^2$.

Comment: $(2−3) = (5, -3)$ is that right? and also what does find $L(2t-3)$ using the matrix A mean?

Comment: You are mixing something. What you probably mean is that $2t - 3$ has the representation $(5, -3)$ in the basis $S$ and this is true. Calculating $L(2t - 3)$ without matrix gives you $L(2t - 3) = t^2 (2t - 3) = 2t^3 - 3t^2$. Now in order to find $L(2t - 3)$ in the basis $T$, you have to multiply $A$ with the vector $(5, -3)$, similar to what you have did in your first comment.

Comment: is there anything i supposed to do with $2t^3-3t^2$?

Comment: The exercise does not tell you so.