# Find ordered basis of matrix of $T_1(p)=p(1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working with an exercise regarding basis, I.e. I'm training to my exam. Have a look at the question!

---

Let $T_1:\mathbb{P}_3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $T_1(p)=p(1)$.

(a) Show that $T_1$ is linear.

(b) What are the matrix $T_1$ relative to the ordered basis $B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ for $\mathbb{P}_3$ and basis $B'=\{1\}$ for $\mathbb{R}$.

(c) Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and define $T_a(p)=p(a)$. What are the matrix $T_a$ relative to the same basis as in (b).

---

My work:

(a) I show that $T_1$ is indeed linear since $T_1(p+q)=(p+q)(1)=p(1)+q(1)=T_1(p)+T_1(q)$. Further, let $r\in \mathbb{R}$ then $T_1(pr) =pr(1)=rp(1)=rT_1(p).$

I hope someone can help me with question (b) and (c). I do not really understand the notation to find the matrix. Any suggestion would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188704/linear-algebra-question-an-example/3188762#3188762) of mine helpful. I talk about the general process of computing a matrix based on a linear operator and basis. I also do the classic example of differentiation on $\Bbb{P}_2$, without skipping too many steps.

Comment: Thank you Theo Bendit. But I do not have to differentiate here, all I see is that I get a matrix with just one column with a single 1 and the rest is zero? And that is a vector. 

I've tried this kind of problem before with $B=\{x^3,x^2,x\}$ and $B'=\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ and where $Tp(x)=p(x)-p'(x)$. This was easy, but this problem I work with now does not contain any $x$ and therefore I do not really know to continue, does it make sense?

Comment: Differentiation is just an example of a linear map. I used it because it's not "immediately clear" how it turns into a matrix, which is much the same deal as $T_1$ (or $T_a$). The presence of $x$ is not really important; it's a dummy variable. Try considering, for example, $p(x) = x^2$. What is $T_1(p)$? Note: it's just a question of evaluating the function at a point.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to find is

$\displaystyle T_{1} =[[ T( b_{0})] \ [ T_{1}( b_{1})] \ [ T_{1}( b_{2})] \ [ T_{1}( b_{3})]]$

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
b_{0} =p( t) =1\\
p( 1) =1\\
T_{1}( b_{0}) =1
\end{array}$

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
b_{1} =p( x) =x\\
p( 1) =1\\
T_{1}( b_{1}) =1
\end{array}$

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
b_{2} =p( x) =x^{2}\\
p( 1) =1^{2} =1\\
T_{1}( b_{2}) =1
\end{array}$

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
b_{3} =p( x) =x^{3}\\
T_{1}( b_{3}) =p( 1) =1^{3} =1
\end{array}$

So

$\displaystyle T_{1} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$